# How to dynamicallly pass the routing coordinates to leaflet-routing using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I am trying to create an app that will take source and destination location from the autocomplete box and the map shows the route between the two points:

[image: ScreenShot:]

I have used the two useState to store the value for Source and Destination. After that, I am passing those two values as props to my Routing component. But the problem is that in my Routing component I am receiving the props data for destination as 'undefined'.

Please find my sandbox code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-currying-recs9).

**Note:** In above code for now I have directly set the coordinates for Destination.

I am not able to figure out why it is behaving this way. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the prop you are passing in `App` component and the prop you are receiving in `Routing`.

You are passing `desitinationCity` prop while you are expecting `destinationCity` prop so therefore it is always undefined.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3-how-to-dynamicallly-pass-the-routing-coordinates-to-leaflet-routing-using-react-hooks-852ji)

Comment: Oh! Damn it. Thanks Yes just now realized.